# VS2012 no typescript intelisence

Tags: visual-studio-2012, intellisense, typescript

I have typescript installed on my visual studio 2012 but when I edit file there is no intellisense at all. Even simple javascript without fancy typescript checking. Do you know what should I do in order to fix it and set it to run?

Comment: what is the version of typescript you are working with ?

Answer (score 1):

I did but it did not worked for me. I restarted pc and ect. but still nothing. Good news I found solution which worked for me and maybe will help someone else C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio this is the pass for visual studio caches and extensions and I simply deleted it and restarted my vs and installed back my extensions and tools and all works

Answer (score 0):

install the latest tooling package: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=282650

and the latest Web Essentials: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6